# Extracting array from response string

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, type-conversion

I have a response like below from node how do I extract it to be as array in java

```
[
   {
      "userName":"Steve",
      "date":"Tue Aug 13 18:44:23 GMT+05:30 2013",
      "message":"Good morning sir."
   }
]
```

Note : finally did it guys, sorry for wasting you guys time, see my last comment :)

i'm making an http request to server written node, and in server i'm sending an array of objects [{}, {}, ...] back to java, 
now coming to java, i'll read the response using InputStream and constructing the result String.

and i'm getting the string like specified above, what i want is like how to convert the string to array so that i can loop and access the objects in the array

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet('some uri');
HttpEntity httpentity = httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

private void renderResponseAndQueueResults(HttpEntity httpentity) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = httpentity.getContent();
                    String result = convertStreamToString(is);
                    is.close();
                    appendResultToMap(result);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;

                try {
                    while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                    try{
                        is.close();
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
```

the return of the convertStreamToString is an String like

```
[
   {
      "userName":"Steve",
      "date":"Tue Aug 13 18:44:23 GMT+05:30 2013",
      "message":"Good morning sir."
   }
]
```

now how can i loop through it

Comment: JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
were result is the response string;

Comment: you probably have considered using a json library, what have you done?

Comment: I'm really not good in java sorry, i just got the result like specified how do i convert into a array

Comment: OK, if it was in js I would have wanted it like an array of objects, were i can loop and access each object and process other queries

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: @Beast You've already seen `JSONArray`. Check out its `getJSONObject` method. Using that you can access an object in the array, and access object fields by key.

Comment: Thanks @JasonC, will try it and will let you know

Comment: did it guys :)
like String r = convertStreamToString(httentity);
JSONArray r = new JSONArray(r);

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the JSON library APIs: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html.

This may be something you want:

```
//process the JSON array parsed out from the source string
for (int i = 0; i < arr .length(); i++) 
{
    //get each JSON object of the array
    JSONObject iObj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

    //access the content of the JSON object, like print it
    System.out.println(iObj.getString("userName"));
}
```

Comment: so i need to like String s =  convertStreamToString()
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(s);